Wix 5 Bootstrapper Installer Reopens After Install/Uninstall Completes
I use Wix 5 WixStandardBootstrapperApplication. In the Bundle I added my WPF application to the chain
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Id="Setup" SourceFile="$(var.MyProject.Setup.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes">
                <MsiProperty Name="AddDesktopShortcut" Value="[AddDesktopShortcutMsiVariable]" />
                <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>

and I added a custom action in which I install the ImDisk bat file.

string installCmd = $"/silent /lang:english /installfolder:\"C:\\Program Files\\ImDisk\" > install.log 2>&1";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(".....\\ImDisk\\install.bat", installCmd );

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            var proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            

And after the installation is complete, a new copy of the installer opens for some reason.
enter image description here
If I remove silent install ImDisk from CustomAction everything is fine.
Tell me what I'm doing wrong. Why does the installer reopen after the installation is complete? What's interesting is that there is no such problem in Wix 3 WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.
I expect after installation/uninstallation is complete not to show the installer again

If you have a problem with install.bat, that you would like assistance with, then we need to see its content. If you are certain that there is nothing in install.bat relevant to your reported problem, then please remove your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, as it is of no use to the people who follow that tag, or use it in searches etc.
